# Display different names for values in Struts2 select tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have the following enum

```java
public enum AccountType {
  ADMIN,
  MANAGER
}
```

Now, in my Struts form I have the following tag:

```xml
<s:select name="account.accountType" list="{'ADMIN', 'MANAGER'}" />
```

This will generate the following field.

[image]

Is there any way to make it generate Administrator instead of ADMIN and Manager instead of MANAGER without editing the enum on the backend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In S2 instead of hard-coding your enum values into list in a JSP you can directly retrieve values from the enum itself using `@package.Enum@values()` notation. And use `listValue` attribute to show whatever you want based on some conditions.

For example:

```xml
<s:select name="account.accountType" list="@com.AccountType@values()"
          listValue="top == @com.AccountType@ADMIN ? 'Administrator' : top" />
```